Using try with resources for a Java Files.walk stream created in a separate method
Working on a project I encountered a situation which I do not know how to properly solve. I am not sure if my solution is the best I could use. But let me introduce the problem (I reproduced it as simply as I could).
There is a class (which is not properly written) which simply gets filenames from directory:
public class StreamTest
{
    public List<String> getList(Path dir) {
        return getStream(dir)
                .map(filename -> filename.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }


    private Stream<Path> getStream(Path dir)
    {
        if (Files.exists(dir)) {

            try {
                Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(dir, 1);

                return stream
                        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                        .map(dir::relativize);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

and Main.class
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path dir = Paths.get("C:\\Projects\\Tests\\Walk");

        StreamTest streamTest = new StreamTest();

        List<String> list = streamTest.getList(dir);

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}

It works but you see what's wrong? Files.walk(dir, 1) should be run with try-with-resources.
But when I replace:
try {
    Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(dir, 1);

with
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(dir, 1)) {


I receive IllegalStateException.
And now question:
Is this approach correct at all? I mean getting stream from method and working on it? But how to properly use try-with-resources in that situation?
The workaround is to return List of some mapped type (e.g String) instead of Stream from getStream and work with it in getList method but I am curious if there is good answer to the question asked.
Certainly I may do all job in one method but hypothetically I may call getStream from couple of other methods.


I receive IllegalStateException.

That's because you've closed the stream before you try to access anything from it. A try-with-resources in the getStream method will close the stream when that method returns; so you won't be able to read the stream in getList.
Put the try-with-resources in getList:
    public List<String> getList(Path dir) {
        try (Stream<Path> stream = getStream(dir)) {
          return stream
                  .map(filename -> filename.toString())
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

    }


I expected that answer and it seems reasonable. The only thing is that IDE (IntelliJ) still complains about using Files.walk without try-with-resources (in getStream method). So I will wait a while before I accept the answer.

@Zadra that’s because the IDE doesn’t realize that the resource you’re returning to the caller is effectively the same you created, as what you return, is the object returned my map, not the object held in the stream variable. You may try to get rid of the variable and simply write return Files.walk(dir, 1) .filter(Files::isRegularFile) .map(dir::relativize); and maybe the IDE considers the fluent use as one resource which will be returned to the caller.

IDE still complains for that. But as this answer is fine for me and in some circumstances I may ignore IDE warning I accept this answer. Thank you.

As an appendix I'd like to mention that when you simply return Files.walk(dir, 1) (without .filter and .map) IDE stops complain.

You can use the try with resources if you don't use a separate method for getStream() :
public List<String> getList(Path dir) {
    if ( Files.exists(dir)) {
        try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(dir, 1)) {
            return stream
                    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                    .map(dir::relativize).map(filename -> filename.toString())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch ( IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return null;
}

The try-with resources closes the Stream as soon as the try-with-resources block is done, which is causing your issue.
In the above example, all remains within the try-with-resources block, so the Stream can still be used to find the List you want.
